# Big distance matrix (17Gb) to pairwise distance list in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

So I have a very large distance matrix 17Gb that I am trying to convert to a pairwise distance list. I can do this without any problem if my dist object is small. But I can't do it with my big dist. Any suggestions?

```
library(spaa)
small_dist <- dist(small_df, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)

#Pairwise distance, write only if dist <2
pairlist_small <- subset(dist2list(as.dist(t(small_dist))), value <2) 

> head(pairlist_small)
     col row     value
1    1:1 1:1 0.0000000
7    2:7 1:1 0.1732051
62   1:2 1:2 0.0000000
73  3:13 1:2 0.1732051
123  1:3 1:3 0.0000000
139 4:19 1:3 0.1732051
```

However when I do the same operation with a big dist I get an error

```
big_dist <- dist(big_df, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
pairlist_big <- subset(dist2list(as.dist(t(big_dist))), value <2) 
Error in t.default(dist) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: ../../../../R-3.6.1/src/main/array.c:1556
```

Any ideas how to do the same in this big distance that is the one I am interested in?

Comment: Perhaps this is an “A/B problem”? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: The points are coordinates in a grid and I am trying to find out which are their closest points in a range so then I can see how the grid looks like. which is why I calculate the distance of each point to another and then filter to get interactions that are only close ones. I hope that explains it a bit.